# find a function in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I am learning cakephp. can someone explain me what this is for

```
$this->RunFunction->bindModel(array('belongsTo'=>array('Audio','Image','Video')));
```

where would I find the RunFunction. Its in a plugin folder of cakephp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it a model in the plugin?  The models would be found in app/plugins/pluginname/models...

So app/plugins/name/models/run_function.php I guess.

Comment: I see it there but why is it run_function instead of RunFunction.php

Comment: Cake has its conventional methods of naming things... file names containing underscores turn into camel-cased class objects.  Takes a bit of getting used to, but I think it's pretty consistent...

Comment: @Autolycus if your question is answered, indicate so with a tick ;)